# How do I inspect a Class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop, reflection

**Update** I fixed up the code to eliminate duplication of overridden methods and track originator of property or method by implementing [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890480/how-do-i-inspect-a-class-in-objective-c/1892127#1892127)'s suggestion. Haven't tackled property types yet (will probably start with `property_getAttributes()` when I do). Also stripped out vestigial underscores.

---

Basically I need a way to remind myself what methods and properties are available on a given object without hopping all the way down the inheritance tree.

I've cooked up the following function but it leaves a bit to be desired:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSInteger inspectClass_alphabeticSort(id string1, id string2, void *reverse)
{
    if ((NSInteger *)reverse == NO)
    {
        return [string2 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:string1];
    }
    return [string1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:string2];
}

void inspectClassStopAt(Class inspectedClass, Class stopClass)
{
    Class originalClass             = inspectedClass;
    NSString *originalClassString   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", originalClass];
    NSString *inheritancePath       = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", originalClass];

    Method *methods;
    objc_property_t *properties;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int methodCount;
    unsigned int propertyCount;
    int reverseSort = NO;

    NSArray *sorted;
    NSArray *methodsAndPropertiesKeys;
    NSMutableDictionary * methodsAndProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];

    NSString *inspectedClassString;
    NSString *methodOrPropertyName;
    while (inspectedClass != stopClass)
    {
        inspectedClassString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", inspectedClass];
        if (inspectedClass != originalClass)
        {
            inheritancePath = [inheritancePath stringByAppendingFormat:@" : %@", inspectedClass];
        }

        methods     = class_copyMethodList(inspectedClass, &methodCount);
        properties  = class_copyPropertyList(inspectedClass, &propertyCount);

        for (i=0; i<methodCount; i++)
        {
            methodOrPropertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%s", sel_getName(method_getName(methods[i]))];

            if (![methodsAndProperties objectForKey:methodOrPropertyName])
            {
                [methodsAndProperties setObject:inspectedClassString forKey:methodOrPropertyName];
            }
        }

        for (i=0; i<propertyCount; i++)
        {
            methodOrPropertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %s", property_getName(properties[i])];

            if (![methodsAndProperties objectForKey:methodOrPropertyName])
            {
                [methodsAndProperties setObject:inspectedClassString forKey:methodOrPropertyName];
            }
        }

        inspectedClass = [inspectedClass superclass];
    }
    free(methods);
    free(properties);

    methodsAndPropertiesKeys = [methodsAndProperties allKeys];
    sorted = [methodsAndPropertiesKeys sortedArrayUsingFunction:inspectClass_alphabeticSort context:&reverseSort];

    NSLog(@"%@", inheritancePath);
    for (NSString *key in sorted)
    {
        if (![[methodsAndProperties objectForKey:key] isEqualToString:originalClassString])
        {
            NSLog(@"\t%@ (%@)", key, [methodsAndProperties objectForKey:key]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"\t%@", key);
        }
    }
}

void inspectClass(Class inspectedClass)
{
    inspectClassStopAt(inspectedClass, [NSObject class]);
}
```

And some sample output from `inspectClass([TextMap class]);`:

```
TextMap : Surface
     position (Surface)
     size (Surface)
    -addChild: (Surface)
    -dealloc
    -init (Surface)
    -initWithFile:
    -position (Surface)
    -render
    -setPosition: (Surface)
    -setSize: (Surface)
    -setText:
    -size (Surface)
    -update (Surface)
```

Comment: What's the use case for this? I could see it being useful in the debugger console, except that there, you can do code completion to get the same information.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to Objective-C so I'm iterating. A lot. Not to improve or refactor code but just to get it working. Properties and method signatures change a lot from my original expectations and design. It'd be nice to be able to just dump the current signature of a class without having to hit three or four source files to piece together a clear picture. Code completion doesn't work for me because of all the non-specific methods and properties inherited from NSObject.

Comment: Looks like the answer to this question is in the question!  Nice work.  This helped me out a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need is an NSMutableDictionary, keyed on the selector names. Add each selector name to the dictionary as a key, with the class name as the value. You can search the dictionary before adding a selector, to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

A nice helper/wrapper for the c libraries provided with runtime.h is https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime

I'm just starting to use it but it definitely looks promising.

As far as use case, mine is simply to provide an inspector to build a self wiring UI that can be attached to an object graph.  That's alot of potential duplicate code reduction.