# How to obfuscate all code in project IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, obfuscation

I have a problem to obfuscate the project codes to protect source.

- is this possible to Obfuscate all project source codes.
  if yes, please guide me.

Comment: You want to make the code UNCLEAR? Huh.... why?

Comment: Why? It's not java, once built you can't "read it".

Comment: @Shebuka yes, you can. You just need the right tools. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890480/how-do-i-inspect-a-class-in-objective-c amongst the MANY resources on the subject.

Comment: my target is not make the code unclear  just wanna to learn how to Obfuscate the code .  Exm: https://github.com/pjebs/Obfuscator-iOS                     But its not work for me

Comment: @Supertecnoboff part of the common strengthening practice in the security world is to rename your variables and classes using code obfuscation to make it more difficult for hackers to inspect and modify your code. This is typically done in most financial applications. See this discussion thread on Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129296/the-case-for-code-obfuscation

Comment: @ekscrypto yes, and? Class name, methods and variables obfuscation is not what OP asked. And as I said actual source code obfuscation is useless in Objective-C, as also you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: @Shebuka The OP asked if it was possible to obfuscate all project sources, but also added the "objective-c" tag which seems to indicate he is trying to obfuscate Objective-C code.  That being said, it IS possible, just difficult and requires some careful approach when creating your app in the first place.  Avoiding storyboards/xib and creating all your view controllers in code is one of the base approach that has to be done if you plan on doing code obfuscation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C code cannot be 100% obfuscated. There are some [open source](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename) and some [commercial](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/ixguard) tools that will obfuscate the class name, the custom methods and variables, but be aware that they can easily break and crash your app.

For example, if you use a custom view controller class in your storyboard, and your code obfuscation changes the class names in the source file but not the storyboard, instantiating that custom view controller will crash your app or at the very least makes it impossible to instantiate your custom view controller.

Similarly, Objective-C variable binding can be difficult if not impossible. Objective-C was designed from the ground up to be inspectable and modifiable. Obviously all of the UIKit delegate/protocol methods cannot be obfuscated. `viewDidLoad` will always be called `viewDidLoad`.

Good luck!

---

**Edit:**

There seems to be a LLVM replacement that handles the code obfuscation for you, check out [Obfuscator-LLVM Wiki](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki).

Comment: is there any easy way to do it  any other options or tools

Comment: There is no easy way to do code obfuscation in Objective-C. It is possible, but be ready to be extremely limited in how you do your development. There are plenty of posts on the subject if you search for them on StackOverflow or your favorite search engine.

Comment: You might wish to look at [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename). It's an open-source fork of ios-class-guard that fixes many issues and has been maintained for new versions of Xcode/iOS. (Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, who make PPiOS-Rename.)

Comment: @NathanArthur I updated the "Open Source" link to PPiOS instead of iOS-class-guard.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Enes, please submit a request at https://www.preemptive.com/contact/contactus; that will get you to the right person. @ekscrypto, thank you!

Comment: Come to find out, PPiOS-Rename, only works with Objective-C and will fail if the app includes any Swift. See comment on their repo: https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename/issues/4

Comment: Thanks for the update, hopefully they get to fix that soon